# GRPC: Sending messages from Python to C#, best method?

Tags: python, c#, protocol-buffers, grpc, redhat

I am working on a project that just scrapes data from 3 devices (2xserial and 1xssh). I have this part implemented no problem.

I am now heading towards the second part where I need be be able to send the data I need using protobuf to the clients computer where they will receive and display on their own client.

The customer has provided examples of their GRPC servers, and it's written in C#.

Currently, for security reasons, our system uses RedHat 8.3 and I am using a SSH Protocol Library called Paramiko for the SSH part. Paramiko is a Python library. Also the machine I am extracting data from only runs on Linux.

---

Here are my main questions, and I apologize if I got nowhere.

1.) The developer from the client side provided us with a VM that has a simulator and examples written in C# since their side was written in C#. He says that it's best to use the C# because all examples can be almost re-used as it's all written, etc. While I know it's possible to use C# in Linux these days, I've still have no experience doing so I don't know how complicated/tedious this can get.

2.) I write code in C# and wrap all the python code, which is also something I've never done, but I would be doing this all in RedHat.

3.) I keep it in python because sending protobuf messages works across languages as long as it is sent properly. Also from the client side, I'm not sure if they will need to make adjustments if receiving protobuf messages written in Python(I don't think this is the case because it's just serialized messages, yea?).

Any advice would be appreciated. I am looking to seek more knowledge outside my realm.

Cheers,
Z

Comment: Do they have a .proto schema? Or is their server using a "code first" approach that doesn't use an explicit schema?

Answer (score 0):

If you're happy in Python, I would use option 3. The key thing is to either obtain their .proto schema, or if they've used code-first C# for their server: reverse-engineer the schema (or use tools that generate the schema from code). If you only have C# and don't know how to infer a .proto from that, I can probably help.

That said: if you want to learn some new bits, option 1 (using C# in your system) is also very viable.

IMO option 2 is the worst of all worlds.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I do have their proto schema and I am just going with Option 3 for now, and see how things go!